# node syslog outputs "Error processing log message"

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, syslog

In `syslog-ng.conf` I have the following:

```
source s_imp { tcp(ip("localhost") port(514)); };

filter f_imp {program("imp");};

destination d_imp {file("/home/rpr/syslog.log");};

log {source(s_imp); filter(f_imp); destination(d_imp);};
```

I'm using the `syslog` package to log from a node server. This is the code that I have:

```
var impLogger = syslog.createClient(514, 'localhost', {name: 'imp'});
impLogger.crit('hello');
```

The output that I get in `syslog.log` is:

```
Apr  6 16:35:17 127.0.0.1 syslog-ng[18571]: Error processing log message: <NaN>2016-04-06T11:05:17.037Z rpr-Inspiron-3521 imp[18500]: hello
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: you are missing a `;` after `filter(f_imp)` in `log {source(s_imp); filter(f_imp) destination(d_imp);};` ..make it `log {source(s_imp); filter(f_imp); destination(d_imp);};`

Comment: @heemayl - the issue exists even after adding the semi colon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that the priority(severity) value is missing or invalid at the beginning of the message. Try setting it explicitly in your node code (see https://github.com/cloudhead/node-syslog/blob/master/lib/node-syslog.js)

Comment: For future users: `that.options.faculty` had to be changed to `that.options.facility`! [issue on github](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-syslog/issues/5)